# How to calculate correct plane-frustum intersection?

Tags: geometry, line, intersection, perspective, plane

### Question:

I need to calculate intersection shape *(purple)* of plane defined by **Ax + By + Cz + D = 0** and frustum defined by 4 rays emitting from corners of rectangle *(red arrows)*. The result shoud be quadrilateral (4 points) and **important requirement is that result shape must be in plane's local space.** Plane is created with transformation matrix **`T`** (planes' normal is `vec3(0, 0, 1)` in **`T`**'s space).

[image]

### Explanation:

This is perspective form of my rectangle projection to another space *(transformation / matrix / node)*. I am able to calculate intersection shape of any rectangle **without perspective** rays *(all rays are parallel)* by **plane-line intersection** algorithm *(pseudocode)*:

Definitions:

```
// Plane defined by normal (A, B, C) and D
struct Plane { vec3 n; float d; };

// Line defined by 2 points
struct Line { vec3 a, b; };
```

Intersection:

```
vec3 PlaneLineIntersection(Plane plane, Line line) {
    vec3 ba = normalize(line.b, line.a);
    float dotA = dot(plane.n, l.a);
    float dotBA = dot(plane.n, ba);
    float t = (plane.d - dotA) / dotBA;
    return line.a + ba * t;
}
```

Perspective form comes with some problems, because some of rays could be parallel with plane (intersection point is in infinite) or final shape is self-intersecting. **Its works in some cases**, but it's not enough for arbitary transformation. How to get correct intersection part of plane wtih perspective?

**Simply, I need to get visible part of arbitary plane by arbitary perspective "camera".**

[image]

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection between a plane (one Ax+By+Cx+D equation) and a line (two planes equations) is a matter of solving the 3x3 matrix for x,y,z.

Doing all calculations on T-space (origin is at the top of the pyramid) is easier as some A,B,C are 0.

What I don't know if you are aware of is that **perspective** is a kind of **projection** that distorts the `z` ("depth", far from the origin). So if the plane that contains the rectangle is not perpendicular to the axis of the fustrum (z-axis) then it's not a rectangle when projected into the plane, but a trapezoid.

Anyhow, using the [projection perspective matrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) you can get projected coordinates for the four rectangle corners.

To tell if a point is in one side of a plane or in the other just put the point coordinates in the plane equation and get the sign, as shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems inherently mathematic so excuse my mathematical solution on StackOverflow. If your four arrows emit from a single point and the formed side planes share a common angle, then you are looking for a solution to the frustum projection problem. Your requirements simplify the problem quite a bit because you define the plane with a normal, not two bounded vectors, thus if you agree to the definitions...

[image: Description of the mathematical problem]

then I can provide you with the mathematical solution [here (Internet Explorer .mht file, possibly requiring modern Windows OS)](http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflowsimplefrustum). If you are thinking about an actual implementation then I can only direct you to a very similar frustum projection implementation that I have implemented/uploaded here (Lua): https://github.com/quiret/mta_lua_3d_math

The roadmap for the implementation could be as follows: creation of condition container classes for all sub-problems (0 < k1*a1 + k2, etc) plus the and/or chains, writing algorithms for the comparisions across and-chains as well as normal-form creation, optimization of object construction/memory allocation. Since each check for frustum intersection requires just a fixed amount of algebraic objects you can implement an efficient cache.